# Change the Meteor Template Values on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteorite

I am displaying a list of Topics on a modal popup window, where on the modal I have two Buttons next and previous.I want  When i click on the previous button it shows the previous 10 topics and when i click on the next button it shows the next 10 topics. My Template code is this

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="topic_selector_label">Quiz Settings</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover " >
                <tbody>
                {{#each topics}}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="previous_topics">Previous Topics</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="next_topics">Next Topics</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
```

and my js code is

```
'click #next_topics':function(){

    var LIMIT=2;
    skip_topics=skip_topics+2;
    var syllabus = Meteor.syllabi.findOne(Session.get("currentSyllabusId"));
    topics= Meteor.topics.find({subject_id: syllabus.subject_id, level_id: syllabus.level_id},{skip:skip_topics,limit:1})
    return Template.syllabus_design({topics:topics})

},
```

I want to change the list of topics on next and previous button click

Comment: And your question is? :) What kind of result are you getting?

Comment: On button click i want to change the topics liston the template

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem is due to the template not refreshing on click,

see this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1172#issuecomment-19832727

try making `skip_topics` a `Session` variable and print that variable in your template - the same way that awatson1978 suggests in the github issue using his/her `form_changed` session variable.

For deeper understanding of what went wrong in your code see http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity

Comment: Thank You Bobojo, The solution given by you is working fine to refresh the template. But I am facing problems using this is on button click i disable the button but when template refreshes the disabled attribute of button becomes false.